# What is the memory impact of using object-sizeof dependency

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am using `object-sizeof` dependency to know about the batch size.

Here is my array of batch insert queries to be executed on cassandra client:

```
var queries = [...]
var size_in_bytes = require('object-sizeof')(queries);`
```

I would like to reject those batch which will cause cassandra down.

else

Can I re-chunk those batch into smaller sizes and run those queries ?

What would be the better approach ?

Answer (score 1):

I would disperse data throughout several batches, especially if you target more than one partition per batch. Mutations on more than one partition will have a negative impact on performance.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the value for `batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb` in the cassandra.yaml file.

Comment: Yes, that is the shortest path I assume, but increasing batch size would create more connections, I would like to know if I can handle it from nodejs code it self.

Comment: @MrugeshVaghela Okay. Unfortunately I haven't coded in node.js before so I'm unable to answer that. Hopefully someone else will step forward.